# Manipulating data.frames

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a sample survey sheet; something like demographic. One of the columns is `country (factor)` another is `annual income`. Now, I need to calculate *average of each country* and store in new `data.frame` with `country` and corresponding *mean*. It should be simple but I am lost. The data is something like the one shown below:

```
Country  Income($) Education ... ... ...
1. USA    90000      Phd
2. UK     94000      Undergrad
3. USA    94000      Highschool
4. UK     87000      Phd
5. Russia 77000      Undergrad
6. Norway 60000      Masters
7. Korea  90000      Phd
8. USA    110000     Masters
.
.
```

I need a final result like:

```
USA   UK    Russia ...
98000 90000 75000
```

Thank You.

Comment: downvote not from me but please [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and edit your post, as it stands this will likely be closed.

Comment: @user1317221_G, does it look better, if that's what you mean.

Comment: The answer to this question is in almost every  R-tutorial i've seen.  Take the time to go through one of them completely and you'll save yourself an immense amount of time in the long haul.

Comment: @NathanG is right. I would take some time to google & familiarise yourself especially with `ddply` and `aggregate` as there are a lot of great blogs, and these are often used tools.

Comment: Ok thanks. Guys. I didn't know about ddply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

data example:

```
dat <- read.table(text="Country  Income Education 
 USA    90000      Phd
 UK     94000      Undergrad
 USA    94000      Highschool
 UK     87000      Phd
 Russia 77000      Undergrad
 Norway 60000      Masters
 Korea  90000      Phd
 USA    110000     Masters",header=TRUE)
```

Do what you want with `plyr` :

if your data is called `dat`:

```
library(plyr)
newdf <- ddply(dat, .(Country), function(x) Countrymean = mean(x$Income))

# newdf <- ddply(dat, .(Country), function(x) data.frame(Income = mean(x$Income)))
```

and aggregate:

```
 newdf <- aggregate(Income ~ Country, data = dat, FUN = mean)
```

for the output you show at the end maybe `tapply`?

```
tapply(dat$Income, dat$Country, mean)
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a question though. I tried sorting now and used **newdf<-newdf[order(Income),]** But it does not seem to work . It says object "Income" not found. does newdf have different structure? I also tried changing **newdf<-newdf[,order(Income)]** though.

Comment: I think your probably wanting to do something like this: 
`newdf[with(newdf, order(Income)), ]`  check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1296745/1317221) also I added an extra `ddply` line of code in answer for you to help you get a `newdf` with the mean column called `Income`